# How to bind an XQuery external variable in Zorba from PHP?

Tags: php, bind, external, xquery, zorba

Can the [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/html/index.html) XQuery processor [PHP API](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/doc/latest/php/html/index.html) bind to variables declared as `external` within an xquery?

For example this line in an xquery would bind to an external variable named `$foo`;

```
declare variable $foo as xs:string external;
```

But I can't find an example in the Zorba PHP API documentation showing how to do the PHP part of the bind, so that the PHP variable `$foo` becomes bound to the xquery variable `$foo`.

Can it be done?

Comment: Take a look for the `set_variable()` function in the PHP API. I don't know it specifically for PHP, but the C API has this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$query = $this->zorba->compileQuery("declare variable $i external; $i + 1");
$dctx  = $this->zorba->getDynamicContext();

$param = $this->zorba->compileQuery(".");
$itemFactory = $this->zorba->getItemFactory();
$value = $itemFactory->createString("1");

$param->getDynamicContext()->setContextItem($value);

$dctx->setVariable("", "i", $param->iterator());
```

Does this help?